# Files list file for package 'libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, dpkg, 18.04, gparted

So I was trying to install gparted but due to HDD failure the installation was interrupted and now I get a dependency error and I can't reinstall or remove gparted.

That's what I get after running `sudo dpkg -C`

```
 The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)

The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 gparted              GNOME partition editor

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 gparted              GNOME partition editor
 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 C++ wrappers for GTK+ (shared libraries)
```

And by running `cat -A /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtkmm-2.4-1v5\:amd64.list`
It shows a set of weird symbols like these ones
 `)M-zM-^?M-^?HM-^M^UM-^B^M^H^@M-^IM-iM->^A^@^@^@1M-@M-hG)M-xM-^?M-i^OM-zM-^?M-^?M-hM-- M-xM-^?HM-^M=M-n^C^H^@DM-^IM-~1M-@M-hM-\@M-^?M-^?HM-^M^MM-e^F^H^@HM-^M5S^I`

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Please do a `sudo dpkg -C` to let dpkg run some sanity checks. It will most likely also show you hints on how to fix any problems it may have encountered. [Edit] your question and include its full output, and also the output of `cat -A /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtkmm-2.4-1v5\:amd64.list`. Note that you should paste command outputs as code-formatted text though, not as screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by:

1. Accessing **/var/lib/dpkg/info** as root.
2. Moving **libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64** to another folder.
3. Running `sudo apt install --reinstall libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64`
4. Reinstalled **gparted** and now everything is working normally.

Running `sudo dpkg -C` returns no errors now